# Is my JSON structure causing major download size?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This may seem a stupid/obvious question, however, I have started developing an app. (Been working more on the UI/functionality to test the logic and functioning of my app). I imported my JSON file to Firebase's Real-Time Database. The JSON file holds over 22,000 records. Within 2.5 days, I have downloaded 16GB of data.

The reason why I am assuming it's the structure of my JSON is because my JSON file currently looks like this:

```
{ "users" : [
  "-3i23rfafj3wjir32": { // (Firebase auto-id, yes I just spammed my keyboard)
    name:    
    location:    
    age:    
    gender:    
    hobbies:    
    interest:    
    DOB:    
    height:    
    bodyType:    
    hairColour:    
    skinColour:    
    ethnicity:    
    education:    
    //And probably 15-30 more nodes    
    }

  ]

} x 20,000+
```

I make a call to my database by the "name" node/key, I believe, my application is doing the following

- Go to database
- Query & observe each and every entry in the database by the `"name"` node/key
- Append data/entry where `"name"` equals to user's input
- Return

The data is static, and should only be read and return to the user. Would restructuring the database like so, help to drastically reduce the download size:

```
{ "users" : [    
  "bob": {    
    name:    
    location:   
    age:    
    gender:    
    hobbies:   
    interest:    
    DOB:    
    height:    
    bodyType:    
    hairColour:    
    skinColour:    
    ethnicity:    
    education:    
    //And probably 15-30 more nodes    
  }         
]} x 20,000+
```

This way I could avoid querying each and every entry within the database, but rather just by each "name" key/node that equals the user's input. In this example above, "bob" would be the user's input. With regards to multiple entries under the same name, that is completely fine.

Once again, apologies if this is somewhat a obvious answer, but rather than waste time reformatting/restructuring my JSON file I'd like to know if this would help.

Comment: Instead of describing the code that you think is causing this, edit your question to actually include that code. Without seeing the code, there's very little we can do to help you improve the situation.

Comment: The terminology you're using to describe what you're doing doesn't really give us an indication what what's really happening. You say you *I make a call* - what call? Then *Query & observe each and every entry* but that's not the purpose of a query - a query returns a subset of data that matches the query, not the entire database. Also, *The data is static, and should only be read and return to the use* the data is static that means 'unchanging' if you *Append data/entry*, then it's changed and no longer static. Can you clarify the question?